# Cannot read property 'signature' of undefined - react-refresh-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-refresh-webpack-plugin

I am trying to add this library: [react-refresh-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin) to my react application and I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'signature' of undefined #229
```

I followed the Readme of the library to add it and have no clue how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to just remove this plugin that was mentioned in the Readme

```
isDevelopment && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')
```

Only keeping the other plugin was sufficient for it to work:

```
plugins: [isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()].filter(Boolean),
```